# QGIS 3.12.1 fails to export ArcGIS Map Server

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export

QGIS 3.12.1 fails to export ArcGIS Map Server, and the exporting operation ends up with the error that is illustrated in the following screenshots, the TIFF result appears in black screen. For more clarification, please note the following screenshots.

What might be the issue here?

[image]
[image]

---

The Tiff could not be opened in QGis. In my case the export ends up with the following error.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: can you open the tif in QGis?

Comment: Not sure what the question has to do with  ArcGIS Map Server

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for your reply. the tiff could not be opened in QGis.

Comment: @MariamKhayyat still no clearer on what this has to do with ArcGIS Map Server.   Are you saying that the image we can see in QGIS originally comes from an ArcGIS service?